# A utility to demultiplex/extract tracks from an MP4 file

Tags: gratis, open-source, command-line, mp4

I'm using Linux. If I want to demultiplex a Matroska file, I can use [mkvextract](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvextract.html) to do so. But what if I want to do this with an MPEG4 file (.mp4)? Is there an equivalent or similar utility for demultiplexing MPEG4 files?

Required features:

- Gratis
- Libre
- Supports command-line invocation rather than a GUI
- Runs on Linux
- Either stable or actively-maintained

Desired features:

- Has a separate GUI interface (possibly by other authors)
- Actively maintained
- multi-platform

Answer (score 1):

#### [MP4Box](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/MP4Box)

(being part of [GPAC](https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/), an Open-Source Multimedia Project)

MP4Box is the "multimedia packager" utility of the GPAC project. It mainly supports MPEG-4  (`.mp4`) and 3rd-generation partnership project (`.3gp`) files, but can also be used with other file formats, e.g. Audio-Video Interleaved (`.avi`), MPEG-1, MPEG-2 and Matroska (`.mkv`).

Its extraction-and-dumping options are covered on [this page](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/mp4box-dump-opts).

Example of use: Suppose I want to extract track 3 of a file named `my_movie.mp4` to a file named `thesubs.srt`. The command-line would be:

```
MP4Box -raw 3:output=thesubs.srt my_movie.mp4
```

... but if the subtitle format is potentially different, it can also convert the sub for you:

```
MP4Box -srt 3 my_movie.mp4
```

and you'll get `my_movie.srt`.

GPAC (including MP4) is available as a package on various Linux distribution, e.g. on Debian you can install it with `apt install gpac`.